# Prevent View from entering the history stack

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

Having three Views A, B, C with navigation in the the following order:

```
A => B => C
```

where all three views are added to the history stack, the back navigation is in the following order:

```
C => B => A
```

Is there a way to navigate back from View C to View A and skipping View B?

```
C => A
```

I am using MvvmCross with Xamarin.ios.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe search for "gshackles custom presenter" - that will probably unearth some answers in the area you are looking for. If not, then maybe add some more detail about where you are currently and what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi @Stuart thanks for your reply. I rephrased my question, please see the edits. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by suart; Gshackles has some great blog posts about the presenters in MvvmCross. One of them is: http://www.gregshackles.com/presenters-in-mvvmcross-manipulating-the-back-stack/

The line of code that you could use is:

```
MasterNavigationController.PopToViewController(existingViewController, true);
```

Or if you just want to go back to the first (aka root): http://gregshackles.com/presenters-in-mvvmcross-using-presentation-values/

```
MasterNavigationController.PopToRootViewController(false);
```